# Shadowfell and the Prime Material plane

Tags: dnd-4e, forgotten-realms, ravenloft, planes

Is the Shadowfell a possible link from the Prime material plane to the demi plane of dread (Ravenloft)?

If so... are creatures (if lucky enough) able to enter the prime material plane and terrorize the locals in the Forgotten Realm setting?

Or is it simply a one way ticket to the demi plane? (I understand players get sucked into Ravenloft and usually have an impossible time trying to leave) but am curious with reading about it here & there based around 4e if creatures on rare occasions step out of the demi plane and onto the prime material.

Comment: Is this question specific to D&D 4e?

Comment: Yes, I was reading some of the content and read a little about the Shadowfell & it sparked my curiosity :)

Comment: Alright. :) Be sure to tag your question with the system you're using if applicable, unless you're genuinely interested in answers broader than your own system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I've never actually played 4e (just read about it), Ravenloft would be (is?) a part of the Shadowfell, whose [official description](http://www.wizards.com/DnD/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ex/20081124) lists domains of dread pretty similar in concept to what we have in Ravenloft. There's a good chance Ravenloft would be (is?) a larger, relatively constant and permanent group of domains in 4e (as [many have guessed - rather thoroughly (so it's a recommended reading - unofficially](http://forum.rpg.net/archive/index.php/t-610288.html).)

From this it follows that... yes, **on *very, very rare occasions* powerful and intelligent creatures might enter the Prime from the so-called Domains of Dread**. I'd say it's up to you, as a DM to come up with a plausible story for how and why such events might happen. Less intelligent and less powerful creatures are rather unlikely to be escape such a domain. However, the Shadowfell itself has quite a number of such low-key monsters that you can, by a twist of your story, import into/onto the Prime... ;)